# Create core data model (Entity, Attributes) dynamically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I have a project in which the attributes will be coming from another server Database. So after getting those attributes we should create the entities in Coredata. Is there anyway I can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the mentioned blog post for adding Attributes to Core Data Entities dynamically.

[Dynamically Adding Attributes to Core Data Entities](http://www.2pi.dk/tech/cocoa/dynamic_attributes.html)

[Dynamically Adding Attributes to Core Data Entities, Part 2](http://www.2pi.dk/tech/cocoa/dynamic_attributes2.html)